# progressDialog not dismissing after progressDialog.dismiss();

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progressdialog

I have a method which gets a string from a file and puts it inside String variable named username, because the reading from the file takes time, I want a progressDialog to appear untill the function is finished, the preogress dialog does appear but is not dismissed when I use progressDialog.dismiss();

This is the code:

```
public String loadUserFromFile(){

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading User");
    progressDialog.show();

    String username = "default";
    String fileName = "savedUserFile.txt";
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput(fileName);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        username = br.readLine();
        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    username = username.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    return username;
}
```

Comment: Try to debug to see if execution really reaches the dismiss method. Your code looks good to me.

Comment: call dismiss in both catch

Comment: calling dismiss in both catch blocks worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 1st thing to make sure that dialog is not null.

```
 ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
     mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(thisActivity);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

 //If you want to show progress dialog
     public void showProgressDialog(String message) {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.setMessage(message);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }
        }

   //To dismiss progress dialog
    public void dismissProgressDialog() {
            if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Usage:

showProgressDialog("Loading");

or

dismissProgressDialog();